# How can I push changes on a previous commit to a new branch based from this previous commit?

Tags: git, bitbucket

I reverted back 3 commits from HEAD on my master branch and made some changes on that old commit.

Then, when I type `git status`, I am told that `Your branch is behind by 3 commits, and can be fast-forwarded.`

I want to create a new branch based on this old commit and push the changes I made into this new branch.

Is this even possible with Git??

Answer (score 4):

Create a new branch and check it out:

```
git checkout -b my-branch
```

Then you can commit any changes that you want on the new branch.

```
git commit -am 'My changes'
```

Finally, push the new branch:

```
git push origin my-branch
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! I have already reverted back to an old commit and made a bunch of changes. Now I am `behind by 3 commits` and have a bunch of untracked changes in working directory. How do I push these changes to a new branch (which is not created yet) that bases from the old commit?  I need to keep my current branch clean though.

Comment: @Kid_Learning_C See my updated answer. I understand better what you are trying to do.

Comment: @Kid_Learning_C Note that "behind by 3 commits" is referring to your current branch relative to its remote tracking branch. Since you reset the current branch, you probably want to do `git push -f` on that branch. Just be aware that this will effectively delete those three commits.

Answer (score 0):

**My answer would be:**

Create a new branch first branched off from `master`

Follow these steps:

1. Make sure you are on `master` branch first.
2. Create a new branch

   `git checkout -b featureA`

   `git cherry-pick <commit-hash>`

**commit-hash** is the commit number you wanted from the master branch.

Now your new branch is holding the commit from master branch which you wanted to modify. Go ahead and modify the code changes and do,

`git commit`

`git push --set-upstream origin featureA`

Now if you are satisfied with your changes, switch back to master branch.

`git merge featureA`

`git push`

Done.